# Android PrograssBar style

Tags: android, android-progressbar

Why my prograssbar is not shown as a moving prograssbar? It is just a white bar there .
Here is my code , Please help me with this,thank you !

Ive tried to change the color code but still not working .
I want it be something like this :
http://developer.android.com/design/media/progress_themes.png

But in this color :002a5c

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="0dip" />

            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:centerColor="#F8F8FF"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#ffffff"
                android:startColor="#C0C0C0" />

            <stroke
                android:width="25dp"
                android:color="#002a5c" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="0dip" />

                <gradient
                    android:angle="90"
                    android:endColor="#002a5c"
                    android:startColor="#002a5c" />

                <stroke
                    android:width="25dp"
                    android:color="#002a5c" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: add the java code too

Comment: already added .my java code have no problem

Comment: I cannot see your Java code... Only see the xml here

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the java code,I just want to change the color ,only need to change the color codes from above codes..but the questions is i dont know how to change these code to correct position

Comment: This style would seem to work. Did you set it as the progressDrawable and call `setProgress()`?

Comment: Yes I did. this style is working but the color is not correct